# Editing files with Linux Deploy

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a 2013 Nexus 7 that I'm trying to use to replace my laptop. I recently installed Linux Deploy and am running the testing distribution of Debian on the device. I've installed all my productivity suite, and things are so close to perfect. I have one small problem I'm hoping you can help with.

I have a few files, such as emacs org-mode agenda files, that I sync with Dropbox. I recently installed DropSync to download those files and keep them up to date on my device. DropSync allows 2-way synchronization, so editing them on my device should update them in Dropbox. I've set up a symlink to my DropSync'd folders to make it easier to access those files. Currently they are all stored in `/storage/emulated/0/Dropbox`, with the symlink in my home directory created with `ln -s /mnt/0/Dropbox`, because `/mnt/0` is the mount point for `/storage/emulated/0` from my Android fs.

The problem comes when I try to edit the files. Unless I use the `sudo` command in my Debian install, I only have read access to the files. When I run `ls -l` on a directory, I get the following:

```
-rw-rw----. 1 root aid_sdcard_r   0 Sep  3 12:46 filename.example
-rw-rw----. 1 root aid_sdcard_r 242 Sep  3 12:46 filename2.example
```

I've tried running `chmod`, but none of the permissions seem to change. is there a way I can permanently change the file permissions in directories I am syncing, so that I don't have to use `sudo` to edit the files?

The results of `mount` for the mount point of `/storage/emulated/0` are:

```
/dev/loop15 on / type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mod=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,seclabel,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/0 type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
```

Results of `mount` in Android Terminal Emulator are extremely long. The one referring to `/storage/emulated/0` is

```
/dev/fuse  /storage/emulated/0  fuse  rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

My username for the Debian instance is `ryan`.

Comment: Emulated sdcard is usually mounted as fat so you can't manage permissions inside. You might have to check how is that partition mounted.

Comment: @Crayon Sorry if it's a dumb question, but how do I do that?

Comment: np ;) Open a terminal and run: "mount" it should give you a list of all partitions mounted and their options.

Comment: @Crayon I've added the results of the `mount` command. Seems to be using the "fuse" filesystem, if I'm interpreting correctly.

Comment: I think situation might be more complicated than I expected, I am not familiar with chroot environment.
I am not sure I can help you but I can try.
Can you:
 * Post the full result of "mount" excuted from a terminal emulator on android (not inside debian).
 * Check if the same command issued inside debia gives you the same result, if not post that one too.
 * What's username in debian shell? ([username@host ~]$)
 * Where are originally files you want to edit and what did you symlink (files/directory)?

Comment: @Crayon I've added more information to the post. Thank you for your willingness to work with me on this.

Comment: ok, so I think the problem is that sdcard is mounted under /mnt/0 but you are trying to access it under /storage/emulator/0. You can see that directory because root can see everything but it shouldn't be the correct way to access it. Try using /mnt/0 or post ls -l /mnt/0/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16956/discussion-between-ryan-and-crayon).